# jQuery Knob bug in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-knob

I have an issue with [jQuery Knob](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob) in Google Chrome:

Everything displays OK until I change the page and click the browser's back button. The percentage is repeated and the circle doesn't display until I refresh the page. Please check this link for example:

http://gcmdesign.net/temp/knob/

Click the link and then the back button of the browser.

Anyone has any idea why this is happening? I've tested in FF, IE, safari and it displays OK. Only in Chrome I have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because when you get the value with `this.cv` it has the %, so it's not a valid number.

Try this (not tested):

```
$(".dial").knob({
    'draw' : function () { 
        $(this.i).val(this.cv.replace('%','') + '%');
    }
});
```

Comment: @GabrielCiprianMagda errors in console? Can you update your demo site or provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: ok here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/y6ppn/

Just click that link (it will give and 404 error) and then click the back button of the browser.